# How to enable minidumps in Java for Windows

Tags: java

I keep getting and seeing this message

> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

So I need to know

1. How to enable minidumps in Java (on a Windows machine)
2. (optional) How interpret a minidump once I have it

I tried to find an answer for those 2 questions but what I found are very specific answers for niche questions and that did not satisfied me.

Answer (score 17):

You will need the following JVM option:

```
-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash
```

Then the minidump will be as large as the memory used by your JVM.

- To interpret the minidump you can install the free Visual Studio C++ Express edition for your platform: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx
- You will also need the symbols for the DLLs that you are interested in. There is some information on using the Microsoft Symbol server here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503
- You would also need the symbol files for the JVM.

Comment: Where should one get the symbol files for the JVM?

Comment: Could you please share the documentation for -XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash ?

Comment: The parameter has changed to CreateCoredumpOnCrash if you are on JDK 9. CreateMDOC was Windows only. The XX flags are specific to the Java HotSpot Virtual Machine. It is true that there is limited documentation for CreateMinidumpOnCrash. I was able to read and interpret the symbol file in Visual Studio to see where the crash ocured.