# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-7, coredump, minidump

I get an error when I open a project in IntelliJ. It only happens with one Project. I am not even able to modify the code. When I open the project in IntelliJ it instantly shows me an utf-8 file with the error message.

1. I reinstalled IntelliJ
2. I tried changing the directory of the project
3. I tried reinstalling Java

I get this Error message:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000022b3302,
>   pid=5876, tid=7496 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame: V  [jvm.dll+0x113302] Failed to write core dump.
>   Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows If
>   you would like to submit a bug report, please
>   visit:http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you don't get an answer here, you should contact Jetbrains. They have pretty good tech support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable minidumps in Java for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459037/how-to-enable-minidumps-in-java-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

File-> invalidate cache and restart option work for me , for this issue.